# Media Queries in Android

Tags: android, css, media

I would like to use different css files for different android phone device widths.
We have one Samsung Galaxy Mini (device-width: 320px) and one Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (device-width: 360px) for testing. When we use the following code, no css file is loaded:

```
<link href="css/iss_320_530_01_00.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (device-width: 320px)" />
<link href="css/iss_360_640_01_00.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (device-width: 360px)" />
```

What could be the solution?

Comment: are you using phonegap?

Comment: No, I'm using WebView and html, jQuery and CSS only.

Comment: Just found the solution which you could see in the following section.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but now we have another problem: My scrollView's `android:layout_height` was set to `WRAP_CONTENT`. According to the [following doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), it should be set to `MATCH_PARENT`.
I quote from there:

> "It is recommended to set the WebView layout height to a fixed value
>   or to MATCH_PARENT instead of using WRAP_CONTENT. When using
>   MATCH_PARENT for the height none of the WebView's parents should use a
>   WRAP_CONTENT layout height since that could result in incorrect sizing
>   of the views."

I also changed the media queries as follows:

```
<link href="css/iss_320_530_01_00.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and device-width: 320px" />
<link href="css/iss_360_640_01_00.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and device-width: 360px" /> Now, css files are loaded for Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini, but not for Samsung Note 4.
```